# Can I sign up to a Windows 10 free upgrade now and defer the actual install until after the July 29 deadline?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I'm currently somewhere with poor quality internet connections, working on some time-sensitive projects. I'd like to update from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 at some point, but not for a month or so until I'm somewhere with better internet connections, with more time to fix any bugs, glitches or compatibility issues.

Is this possible? Is there any way I can sign up for the free install now before the deadline, but defer performing the install until later when I've got the time and facilities to make sure it happens smoothly?

Comment: as far as i know you need to install it once to match your hardware and windows 10 license. i am not aware of any way to just reserve your upgrade but you can do a full backup, upgrade to 10 then restore to that backup. that way your device will be registered and you can keep using your 8.1 as long as you want.

Comment: No;  There is no "signing up" for the upgrade.  "Signing up" just schedules a time it will be installed, if installed after July 29 2016, you will be promoted to purchase a Windows 10 license after the upgrade happens

Comment: @Ramhound "There is no "signing up" for the upgrade" - MS seems to think otherwise "You can sign up for the Windows 10 upgrade offer in two ways: ..." Source [Upgrade to Windows 10: FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12435/windows-10-upgrade-faq). Do you have a credible reference that the MS FAQ is incorrect?

Comment: @DavidPostill Who knows the reason Microsft uses that word, to describe a process of, confirming you want the upgrade and then choosing the time to install it. The term comes from last year, before Windows 10 1507 was released, and you would confirm you wanted Windows 10 after the "RTM" build was planned to be released.

Answer (score 1):

No.

That is because the licensing component of the free upgrade is a digital entitlement created by Microsoft Activation Technology. "Signing up to upgrade" does not give you this digital entitlement. This is deliberate: Microsoft wants people to move on to Windows 10, not to promise moving on and never doing so.

Comment: The problem with this is: For some people the upgrade simply (and repeatedly) fails. It doesn't help that for every retry the download of 3 GB is done again ...